# Flycheck-Google-Cpplint is not Configured Correctly

Tags: emacs, flycheck, cpplint

I am trying to install flycheck-google-cpplint in my emacs. But I get this error:

```
(flycheck-mode 1)
(eval-after-load 'flycheck
  '(progn
     (require 'flycheck-google-cpplint)
     (flycheck-add-next-checker 'c/c++-cppcheck
                              'c/c++-googlelint 'append)))
(custom-set-variables
   '(flycheck-googlelint-verbose "3")
   '(flycheck-googlelint-filter "-whitespace,+whitespace/braces"))
```

But this does not work. I get the following error:

```
Error: (user-error "Configured syntax checker c/c++-googlelint cannot be used")
```

I don't know why. I installed cpplint and it works fine if I used it from the command line. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

flycheck-google-lint uses cpplint. You have to tell emacs where to find the cpplint.py executable in order to run the syntax check.

You can find the cpplint file [here](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cpplint/cpplint.py).

Then, you need to add this to your init emacs file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(flycheck-c/c++-googlelint-executable "/path/to/cpplint.py"))
```